# Not one letter he sent her

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms, negation

> **Not one letter he sent her,** let alone to give her a phone call.

Is this grammatically correct? What about idiomatically?

P.S.: The reason why I would prefer using it, regardless of how unidiomatic might sound is to emphasize the affirmation. In context it looks a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my ears it sounds poetic, stilted, and old fashioned.

However it will be grammatically/syntactically correct if you change the `to give` to `gave` or omit it completely as suggested.

> Not one letter he sent her, let alone a phone call.

Comment: I like it even better if we strike out "to gave her" altogether: _Not one letter he sent her, let alone a phone call._ That's even less awkward, I think.

Comment: I agree - that is even better, still overly poetic, but better